# Difference between SDK Tools and gradle?

Tags: android

> Arguably the most important parts of this package are in the SDKtools.
> You will need these tools regardless of which version of Android you
> are targeting. These are what will actually create the APK – turning
> your Java program into an Android app that can be launched on a phone.

Then what is the purpose of Gradle?

Answer (score 2):

Gradle is used to automating the build process i.e converting your java files into Dex, proguard , minification, converting res in R class etc while SDK tools are Android SDK Manager (android sdk), AVD Manager (android avd), and emulator (emulator), Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (ddms). Some other important tools areAndroid Virtual Device Manager, Android Emulator, mksdcard, adb, adb shell commands, traceview, ProGuard, zipalign,